# How to invoke multiple components in one html file?

Tags: angular

Hi sorry for what is probably a stupid/simple problem/question, but I am having problems trying to invoke two components in a simple html file for an Angular 6 project.

If I remove app-comp-1, app-comp-2 will show up, but if I have the code for both only the first component will display.

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<app-comp-1>
<app-comp-2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular template requires a closing tag. Opened `<app-comp-1>` hides contents that follow.

Try below.

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<app-comp-1></app-comp-1>
<app-comp-2></app-comp-2>
```